# Create and Edit non-Office documents in SharePoint 2010

Tags: custom, document, com

This is something I've been looking into for a while.

We use sharepoint here as well as our own bespoke bit of software that lets you create and edit our own type of documents.

I've written a COM dll, which I've tested with the following code as a vbs script:

```
Dim obj
set obj = CreateObject("Ctest.SharePoint.OpenDocuments.1")
msgbox obj.EditDocument("c:\mytest.olf", "06FC39A0-2CAA-11D0-B6B7-004095131445")
```

That works a treat.

I've added our file extension to Sharepoint search/indexing.

If I edit DocIcon.xml with the line:

```
<Mapping Key="olf" Value="olf.png" EditText="My Application" OpenControl="Ctest.SharePoint.OpenDocuments.1"/>
```

I get the "The document could not be opened for editing. A Microsoft SharePoint Foundation compatible application could not be found to edit the document." error.

Any idea's on this as I'm not sure what else I can do!

Comment: I don't know if this will help you much, since it is quite an old bookmark, but take a read at Custom OpenDocuments blog post here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/malag/archive/2010/05/13/using-custom-opendocuments-control-to-open-custom-file-types-in-sharepoint.aspx

Comment: That was actually my starting point for this project but I can never get sharepoint to acknowledge the other application.

Comment: Is the control registered on the client machine properly?

Comment: I'll need to check that. Although calling via the vbs script indicates so, i'm sure there's something missing relating it to Sharepoint.

Comment: If it is erroring in the javascript then it will be the control, if the javascript isn't doing anything on the page, the it isn't registered properly in sharepoint.

Comment: My control isnt showing up in %windir%\assembly\ which could probably be the cause of the issue?

Comment: Doesn't look like it's registered properly then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

```
gacutil -i mydll.dll
```

A reboot!

Problem solved!

Comment: You probably didn't need a reboot.. just an `iisreset`. Also, you should consider deploying this via a solution?

Comment: Restarting iis didn't help sadly. I'll deploy it when I'm happy with the the way integration works. It's bare bones at the moment but as long as Sharepoint's talking to my code I'm currently happy...